# Magento: ?___SID=U appearing in some urls

Tags: magento, url

Can someone please explain why ?___SID=U is appearing in some Magento URLs on my site and not others?

I think it has something to do with sessions but I am not entirely clear.  Also, what makes it more confusing is the fact that it's only appearing in some URLs and not others.

I don't need to know how to remove it as I am aware of the setting in the admin area.  I would really like an explanation of what it is, what its purpose is and why it would show on some pages and not others.  id rather understand what's going on fully than blindly follow some advice as to how to remove it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I addition to Brendan's answer, the `___SID=U` is used in the cache as a placeholder for the session ID. It is replaced by `Mage_Core_Model_Url::sessionUrlVar()` which in turn calls `Mage_Core_Model_Url::sessionVarCallback()`. These methods are called from `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::_afterCacheUrl()`, which means that any URL found in block output will contain the correct session ID (if needed).

So to get rid of the parameter in your own code the "right way" use this:

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('some/magento/route'); // might append ___SID parameter
$url = Mage::getModel('core/url')->sessionUrlVar($url); // process ___SID
```

If the string still displays in the rendered page that is a bug. Are you using some custom caching module, or generating URL's using a non-standard way?

Answer (score 11):

The SID is a "session ID". Magento uses this to track a user's activity within the same Magento installation. Normally, Magento powers one website and one store from one installation (database).

Magento could power multiple websites with multiple stores from one installation though. The SID allows users to stay logged in while navigating across these websites/stores.

I *think* if you have the function enabled, the SID is sent when accessing catalog URLs so Magento can update the session with the user's location/state for the current website/store.

If you're not running a multi-website or multi-store environment, it's safe to disable the SID on the frontend.

Comment: hi,Thanks for your valuable info. Do you know how to move the payment part to another web servers to same site ? Really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just something i come across today and though i make a comment, maybe it will help someone.
I found that Magento will format/create an incorrect product url (inc. Session Id) if there were some errors during processing the page. This is not consistent though.
It worth having a look at your server logs for PHP errors.

Comment: Saw the same problem, session ID was showing up in an Ajax call due to a PHP error up the chain.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general Magento 2 bug which is already reported to magento.

Temporary fix is

Go to Document Root,
Find .htaccess and add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) www.abc.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

below.

This should solve the issue. For me this work in M2.1

All the best.

Reference : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5517

Answer (score 0):

I hunted for hours to find this and the precise answer was a combination of the other answers listed here. First, I cranked up my PHP error reporting and error logging (thanks Gergely Varga). I saw this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_strrpos() in /var/www/html/app/code/local/ManaPro/FilterAjax/Model/Observer.php on line 59
```

So, one of our installed extensions requires the `php-mbstring` package, which my server didn't have installed. As soon as I installed that, the `SID=U` URLs all disappeared. (In future I'll be running Magento's pre-install checks before copying an existing install over to a new server!)

Thanks to Vinai too for the background of what this tag is for.

Comment: No, Magento 1.x does not requires `php-mbstring`. See [System Requirements](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html). In your case, it is the 3rd party module _ManaProg_ that requires it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings > Use SID on Storefrontand and set the value to No.
2. Clear the Magento cache