# Magento html?___SID=U at the end of urls

Tags: magento, session, url-rewriting

I have a multistore magento site. SID in front is enabled as I want customers to cross around sites without login issue. 
But I want to remove "html?___SID=" which is at the end of all my urls. 
What can i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento: ?\_\_\_SID=U appearing in some urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300200/magento-sid-u-appearing-in-some-urls)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin => System => Configuration => Web => Session Validation Settings and disable config Use SID on Frontend => No

For more information check [here](http://www.peeledcarrots.com/magento-removing-session-id-sidu-from-the-url/) or check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11307817/1749007)

Comment: I want it to be YES as I have multistore and need SID for stores. Just want to remove  "html?___SID=U f.e.:    "product.html" NOT "product.html?___SID=U

Comment: OR can I use SID only in store switcher not rest of them