# Does an HTML extension in a URL affect Google Analytics tracking or the ability to add marketing pixels to individual pages within the website?

Tags: html

I am a marketer and I am pitching a new client. I noticed that all of the pages on their website end in `.html`. I have never seen this before. Will this structure affect my ability to implement marketing pixels (like the Facebook Ads pixel, DoubleClick by Google advertising pixels, and more)? Also, will I be able to use Google Tag Manager to set up Google Analytics Event Tracking (so that I can measure on page actions, like button clicks)? Maybe the `.html` URL structure doesn't matter and I can move forward with marketing measurement setup for the website as normal but I just wanted to check. Here is an example of one of the webpages for reference: https://www.soundstrue.com/store/spiritual-journey.html?___SID=U.Thank you!

Google searches

https://www.soundstrue.com/store/spiritual-journey.html?___SID=U

None experienced yet. This is a new client pitch so I haven't been able to try anything myself. I just want to make sure I can implement my normal marketing measurement setup.

Comment: short answer: no. there is no correlation between the file extension and your ability to add the tracking code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento: ?\_\_\_SID=U appearing in some urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300200/magento-sid-u-appearing-in-some-urls)

Comment: `.html` suffix does not matter, but that server does not seem to handle sessions correctly, which is the actual technical issue here, because the tracked URL will barely match each other on the same page, due to the `___SID` query-string, which should not be there. Lighthouse Audit shows a performance rating of 10/100 ...which might be another technical problem, which directly affects the marketing.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it will not affect your ability to use google analytics or tracking pixels. It is an unrelated detail, and means nothing one way or another.

---

**What does the `.html` mean?**

A URL is just a link to a file on the web server. A link like this:

http://example.com/pages/about.html
(note: this link does not exist, it is just an example.)

links to a file called "about.html" in a folder called "pages" on the webserver.

However, it is possible to just link to a folder instead of a specific page. So, a link like this:

http://example.com/pages

links to a folder called "pages". However, most servers are configured to return a specific file instead of the folder, usually called "index.html".

So, on most servers, the following links are equivalent:

http://example.com/pages

http://example.com/pages/index.html

You are accustomed to servers configured this way, which is why you were surprised to see the `.html`. But this has no impact whatsoever on whether or not you can add additional JavaScript to any of the pages.

---

**Does this mean anything for me?**

Mostly, no. HTML is the language used for all webpages. Some web servers are quite complicated and generate that HTML using other code, but in the end, everything is HTML eventually. In order to add google analytics or tracking pixels, the only requirement is that you add a code snippet into the final HTML that gets sent to the user.

The `.html` file extension *might* (probably does) imply that your client's website is what is called a "static website"; that is, a website where the HTML code for each page is written manually by hand rather than being generated by other code.

The worst-case scenario for you is that you will have to add the tracking code manually into each page that you want to track, rather than being able to just add it to one file and have the whole website tracked automatically.

Comment: it's a Magento site, therefore most HTML should be generated by PHP... and that `.html` suffix is likely being appended with apache2 `mod_rewrite`.